# Java bytecode - Why is offset being skipped?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have this very simple class

```
public class TestImpl2 {
    public TestImpl2() {
    }

    public double run(double param) {
        double d = 7.0D;
        double k = 4.0D;
        if (param < k) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }

        return 0.0D;
    }
}
```

That i compiled with javac and then decompiled with javap to see its bytecode.

```
     0: ldc2_w        #14                 // double 7.0d
     3: dstore_3
     4: ldc2_w        #16                 // double 4.0d
     7: dstore        5
     9: dload_1
    10: dload         5
    12: dcmpg
    13: ifge          23
    16: getstatic     #23                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    19: dload_3
    20: invokevirtual #29                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(D)V
    23: dconst_0
    24: dreturn
```

Lets check offsets

0 - is reserved for "this" reference

1 - is the method parameter

2 - skipped ?

3 - variable "d"

4 - skipped ?

5 - variable "k"

Why were offsets 2 and 4 skipped? Is it because method param, d and k are doubles or is it something completly else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) (emphasis mine):

> Local variables are addressed by indexing. The index of the first
> local variable is zero. An integer is considered to be an index into
> the local variable array if and only if that integer is between zero
> and one less than the size of the local variable array.
>
> *A value of type `long` or type `double` occupies two consecutive local
> variables.* Such a value may only be addressed using the lesser index.
> For example, a value of type double stored in the local variable array
> at index n actually occupies the local variables with indices n and
> n+1; however, the local variable at index n+1 cannot be loaded from.

It is not that indices 2 and 4 are not used. It's just that `param` and `d` are `double`s and they occupy 2 spaces each.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because they are double. In [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-2.html) section 2.6.1 Local variables you can read:

A single local variable can hold a value of type boolean, byte, char, short, int, float, reference, or returnAddress. A pair of local variables can hold a value of type long or double.